# Proper way to pass user uid to my database with Nuxt, Laravel API and Firebase Auth?

Tags: async-await, axios, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, vuex

**What I want to do.**

I'm currently creating a restaurant booking web app with Nuxt, Laravel API and Firebase Authentication.

What I want to do is,

1. Create a new user account in Firebase Authentication.

   ```js
   {
       "email": "User's email address from input",
       "password": "User's password from input"
   }
   ```
2. At the same time, insert a new user account to my local database with user uid as password.

   ```js
   {
       "name": "User's name from input",
       "email": "User's email address from input",
       "password": "User's uid from store/auth.js"
   }
   ```

**Issue**

The registration success to the Firebase Auth and also to the local database as well if it's without uid.
But when I try to add uid, I get this error in Laravel logs.

> 1364 Field 'General error: password' doesn't have a default value

I thought this error occurred because of asynchronous processing, so I added Async to the code, but the result does not change.

**Code**

```js
// register.vue
<script>
import firebase from '~/plugins/firebase'

export default {
  layout: 'auth',
  data () {
    return {
      user: {
        name: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async register() {
      this.$store.dispatch('auth/register',
        {
          name: this.user.name,
          email: this.user.email,
          password: this.user.password
        }
      )
      .then(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/onAuth')
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.$axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users',
          {
            name: this.user.name,
            email: this.user.email,
            password: this.$store.state.auth.userUid
          }
        )
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push('/thanks')
      })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
// store/auth.js

import firebase from '~/plugins/firebase.js'

export const state = () => ({
    userUid: '',
    userEmail: '',
    loggedIn: false,
})

export const actions = {
    async register({ commit }, payload) {
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then((result) => {
            const user = result.user
            commit('loginStatusChange', true)
            console.log('Regist a user was successful')
            commit('setUserUid', user.uid)
            commit('setUserEmail', user.email)
        })
    },

    onAuth({ commit }) {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            user = user ? user : {}
            commit('setUserUid', user.uid)
            commit('setUserEmail', user.email)
            commit('loginStatusChange', user.uid ? true : false)
        })
    }
}

export const mutations = {
    loginStatusChange(state, status) {
        state.loggedIn = status
    },
    setUserUid(state, userUid) {
        state.userUid = userUid
    },
    setUserEmail(state, userEmail) {
        state.userEmail = userEmail
    }
}

export const getters = {
    getUserUid(state) {
        return state.userUid
    },
    getUserEmail(state) {
        return state.userEmail
    }
}
```

**Environment**

- Nuxt 2.15.8
- Laravel Framework 8.72.0
- MySQL 5.7.34
- Firebase Auth

Comment: I think the issue is that your actions aren't composable. They need to return the promises

Comment: When using async, use the await syntax too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your actions aren't [composable](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions) so your Axios post request to Laravel doesn't wait for the previous two actions to complete, therefore `this.$store.state.auth.userUid` is empty at that stage.

1. Have your async actions return a promise that actually waits for things to complete.

   ```js
   export const actions = {
     async register({ commit }, { email, password }) {
       const { user } = await firebase //  note the "await" here
           .auth()
           .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

       commit('loginStatusChange', true)
       console.log('Register a user was successful')
       commit('setUserUid', user.uid)
       commit('setUserEmail', user.email)

       return user //  return the user so consumers can use it
     }
   }
   ```
2. Registering a firebase auth state change listener isn't something you should configure as a Vuex action. I would instead [register this as a plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store/#plugins-in-the-store)

   ```js
   // store/index.js
   import firebase from "~/plugins/firebase"

   const authStateChangePlugin = store => {
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
       user = user ? user : {}
       store.commit("auth/setUserUid", user.uid)
       store.commit("auth/setUserEmail", user.email)
       store.commit("auth/loginStatusChange", user.uid ? true : false)
     })
   }

   export const plugins = [ authStateChangePlugin ]
   ```
3. Wait for your action to dispatch before posting to Laravel

   ```js
   methods: {
     async register () {
       //  note the use of "await"
       const user = await this.$store.dispatch("auth/register", { 
         ...this.user
       })

       await this.$axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users", {
         ...this.user,
         password: user.uid // no need to reference the store here
       })

       this.$router.push('/thanks')
     }
   }
   ```